# Read Cardinality UML Visual studio 2010

Tags: uml, t4

I wish to generate the code using t4 by reading UML class diagram for visual studio 2010. I am able to read the classes and its associations. I wish to read the multiciplity for the associated classes? Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? Where this.Element is type of IClass

```
foreach (IAssociation association in this.Element.GetRelatedLinks<IAssociation>())
{
    var source = association.SourceElement as IClassifier;
    var target = association.TargetElement as IClassifier;

    foreach(var end in association.MemberEnds)
    {
        WriteLine("// mapping:" + end.Name + ": " + end.GetBounds());
    }
}
```

I recall seeing GetBounds() returns a string with at least "1" or "*" as possible values.